# Best solution for persisting GPS coordinates that are received at every 5 seconds on the server?

Tags: architecture, persistence

I implement an application similar with Bolt and Uber and I am looking for the best solution to persist the coordinates of the active drivers.

The clients (iOS and Android apps) send the coordinates (latitude and longitude) at every 5 seconds, and they have to be updated on the server (Spring Boot app) in order to display them on the map of the potential passengers.

My first solution was Redis. I already use it for token revocation (JWT Authentication) and I was thinking to extend it for storing the position of each driver because it is very fast compared to a Relational Database, but the problem is that I don't think that Redis offers complex enough data retrieving methods (like SQL) so I might add unwanted complexity to the business layer when I want to compute all the drivers in the vicinity of a passenger.

The second solution was to store the coordinates in a relational database. Here I would have complex ways to fetch data using SQL, but it is slower. Due to the fact that I consider to update the position of each driver at every 5 seconds I think that this is not the best solution.

What do you think that is the best architecture for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I will throw some ideas.

First we dont know how many app will send the coordinates every 5 sec. If its a couple of app then you can directly store them in db, till it start affecting your db write latency.

If have large no of apps sending coordinates then you can, first store them in Redis. Use Redis with replcation so that you dont loose any data.
Periodically read it from Redis and dump it in database.

You haven't mention what kind of query you are performing on the coordinates.

My guess,

- If you want to show the previous location trail of car, then you can store this data on client side.
- If you want to hot areas with lot of active apps, then you can read it from Redis. Perform calculation and store result in storage, CDN etc. Simultaneously, keep backing data in db.

Database choice can be MongoDB or Postgres. But it will depend on your use case.